# Close Lightdm in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, nvidia, lightdm, xserver

Should I install the official NVIDIA drivers for my NVIDIA 8200?
When I start the installation, it asks me to close the xserver.

Only way to close it is to run the command : `sudo service lightdm stop`because the desktop manager, GDM, is not active in Ubuntu 12.04.

The problem is that when I do stop lightdm , it gives me a login bug.

When I run the `stop service lightdm` command I get a black screen. What can I do to stop the xserver, while avoiding the login bug?

Comment: It seems to me that for some reason you stay at the active virtual console 7 after stopping lightdm. Try switching to VC-1, login then stop lightdm. The magical accord is Ctrl-Alt-F1.

Comment: OK, this is not 'some reason', it is default behavior when you stop lightdm from X session active. So just try suggested solution.